# How to find newest file in a directory and copy to new directory (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, find, archive

I am archiving a Minecraft server daily and want to be able to find the most current archive file in that folder and relocate it to a new directory on both a weekly and monthly basis using CRON.

How would I specify to `find` the newest file, copy to new directory and rename it?

Answer (score 0):

The find-copy command:

`find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 0 -ctime 0 -daystart | xargs cp --target-directory=/path/to/export/folder`

Cron:

first day of each month : `* * 1 * *`

daily at midnight `0 0 * * *`